# Get ip address from a request mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ip-address

I'm trying to get the ip address of the device that is making the request. This should work in both self hosted or hosted on a server with internet access.

I've tried this:

```
//Get Visitor IP address method
    public string GetVisitorIpAddress()
    {
        string stringIpAddress;
        stringIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

        if (stringIpAddress == null) //may be the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is null
            stringIpAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]; //we can use REMOTE_ADDR
        else if (stringIpAddress == null)
            stringIpAddress = GetLanIPAddress();

        return stringIpAddress;
    }

    //Get Lan Connected IP address method
    public string GetLanIPAddress()
    {
        //Get the Host Name
        string stringHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        //Get The Ip Host Entry
        IPHostEntry ipHostEntries = Dns.GetHostEntry(stringHostName);
        //Get The Ip Address From The Ip Host Entry Address List
        System.Net.IPAddress[] arrIpAddress = ipHostEntries.AddressList;
        return arrIpAddress[arrIpAddress.Length - 1].ToString();
    }
```

But in both cases i get:  "::1".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You know that's part of an IPv6 address, right?

Comment: No I didn't lol. Never actually needed an ip address. So I haven't done much with it :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IPv6 `::1` is the same as `127.0.0.1` in IPv4. So when you run it from your local machine this is what you should be getting.

You can try to modify your hosts file, or try to access the application by it's IP `http://192.168.0.1` (for example).